# How to create a TypeScript module that matches complex paths?

Tags: typescript, module

I would like to declare a global module that targets all image imports and another that targets all icon imports since these are treated differently in the project I am working on. Image imports usually come from an `images` folder and `icons` from an `icons` folder but their extension can be the same.

According to the [modules wildcard documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#wildcard-module-declarations) I thought of something like this:

```js
declare module '*/icons/*' {
    type IconType = { viewBox: string, symbol: string };

    const icon: IconType;
    export = icon;
}

declare module '*/images/*' {
    const url: string;
    export = url;
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Is there any other way of doing this? In Flow it is possible to define this with `module.name_mapper` but how to do it in TypeScript?

Answer (score 2):

Try to put declare the modules by file suffix, one declaration per file type.

```js
declare module '@my/module/src/images/*.svg' {
  type IconType = { viewBox: string, symbol: string };

  const icon: IconType;
  export = icon;
}

declare module '@my/module/src/icons/*.svg' {
  const resource: string;
  export = resource;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what is mentioned on the TypeScript website but this won't work for me since both images and icons have the suffix `*.svg`. Is there another way?

Comment: thanks for the update. I tried it but it still doesn't work. To give an example: an import path can look like this: `@my/module/src/icons/checkbox/checked.svg`.

Comment: I've tested it a bit, the only solution that works is to specify the entire path

Comment: Did you try add `**` in glob pattern, like `@my/module/src/icons/**/*.svg` ?

Comment: @EugeneObrezkov, I've tried it, it doesn't work as well

Comment: I tried `*/icons/**.svg`, `**/icons/**/*.svg` and `*/icons/**/*.svg`  but none of them worked :/  This is the last thing blocking me from moving to TypeScript D: I can't believe there is no way of doing this :/

Comment: I can't specify the full path since the `module` could be any module from inside my monorepo.

Comment: Basically these declarations are for modules, that means you need to specify one for each module that you at consuming.

Comment: To me it doesn't make any sense since it is possible in Flow but not in TypeScript. I can't believe this isn't a common use case :/ All image and icon imports will return the same so creating a declaration for each icon / image is a waste of time...

Comment: but your use case is the unique one, cause you have 2 or more behaviours for the same file. Usually, for svg, the usage is the same, therefore, `*.svg` is enough.

Comment: I see... Well I added a feature request: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38638. In the meantime I guess I'll have to come up with some kind of solution that relies on @ts-ignore 