# Use glob pattern in typescript declaration files

Tags: typescript, webpack, glob, tsconfig, webpack-file-loader

I'm using [file-loader](https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/), a webpack plugin that converts media imports as their URLs, so in `import src from './image.png'`, `src` is a `string`.

I know I can make typescript understand that by having this in some declaration file:

```
declare module '*.png' { export default ''; }
declare module '*.jpg' { export default ''; }
declare module '*.jpeg' { export default ''; }
declare module '*.svg' { export default ''; }
declare module '*.gif' { export default ''; }
declare module '*.avif' { export default ''; }
```

However it's very wordy, and this doesn't work:

```
declare module '*.{png,jpe?g,svg,gif,avif}' { export default ''; }
```

Is there a parameter in my tsconfig.json or a CLI option I can use so that TypeScript handles real glob patterns in declaration files?

Comment: Relevant [suggestion](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38638)

Comment: Related: [How to create a TypeScript module that matches complex paths?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61816777/8186898)

Answer (score 0):

According to [microsoft/TypeScript#38638](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38638), TypeScript currently does not support globs in declaration files

> #### Improve declare module wildcards so that they can match parts of a path more like a glob
>
> Status: opened
>
> [...]
>
> This is an example of what I would like to be able to do:
>
> ```
> declare module '@my/**/icons/**/*.svg' { }
> declare module '@my/**/images/**/*.svg' { }
> ```

Thanks [@Aleksey L.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1113002/aleksey-l) for pointing me in this direction in the comments.